# Creating a column which will start taking value 1 with the smallest value of another column and increases by 1 up to the largest value

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(3)

n=12
x <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
y <- (x==1) * rexp(n, 1/365)
group <- sample(rep(1:2,each=6))

dat <- data.frame(x, y, group)
dat2 <- with(dat, dat[order(group, y),] )
```

`dat2` becomes :

```
   x          y group
1  0    0.00000 1
3  0    0.00000 1
2  1   41.79209 1
5  1   57.73478 1
10 1  441.58968 1
6  1 1541.61783 1
4  0    0.00000 2
7  0    0.00000 2
8  0    0.00000 2
9  1  141.78670 2
11 1  432.98895 2
12 1  638.24612 2
```

Now I want to create another column `i` in `dat2` which will take value 0 if `x==0` and will take value 1 for the smallest `y` of both group 1 & 2;  `i` will take value 2 for the second smallest `y` of both group. That is, within each group, I will position `y` in ascending order except for which `x==0`.

The column `i` will  be as following:

```
   x          y group i
1  0    0.00000 1     0
3  0    0.00000 1     0
2  1   41.79209 1     1
5  1   57.73478 1     2
10 1  441.58968 1     3
6  1 1541.61783 1     4
4  0    0.00000 2     0
7  0    0.00000 2     0
8  0    0.00000 2     0
9  1  141.78670 2     1
11 1  432.98895 2     2
12 1  638.24612 2     3
```

For this, I  first split the data frame `dat2` with respect to group:

```
dat3 <-  split(dat2, dat2$group)

dat31 <- dat3[[1]]

dat31$i <- with(dat31, ifelse(x==0, 0, 1:length(x[x==1]))  )
```

But `i` is taking value according to row numbers. I have to give a condition on `y` in the code for creating `i`, but I am not understanding how is to incorporate such condition?

Any more elegant function to create the column `i` is appreciated.

Comment: As long as each group is ordered by `y`, `library(dplyr); dat2 %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(i = cumsum(y > 0))` or in base, `dat2$i <- ave(dat2$y, dat2$group, FUN = function(x){cumsum(x > 0)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat2)`), grouped by 'group', get the logical vector (`y > 0`) and find the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) and assign (`:=`) it to new column 'i'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat2)[,  i:= cumsum(y>0) , group]
dat2
#   x          y group i
#1: 0    0.00000     1 0
#2: 0    0.00000     1 0
#3: 1   41.79209     1 1
#4: 1   57.73478     1 2
#5: 1  441.58968     1 3
#6: 1 1541.61783     1 4
#7: 0    0.00000     2 0
#8: 0    0.00000     2 0
#9: 0    0.00000     2 0
#10:1  141.78670     2 1
#11:1  432.98895     2 2
#12:1  638.24612     2 3
```

---

Or another compact option is `ave` from `base R`

```
dat2$i <- with(dat2, ave(y > 0, group, FUN = cumsum))
```

Comment: In `setDT`, inside the bracket `[]`, why there isn't any argument before the first comma [`,` i:= cumsum(y>0) , group]?

Comment: @Leaf Because `data.table` follows the format `data.table[i,j, group]`  Here we are not specifying the 'i', so it was left as blank

Answer (score 1):

If you know `y` is ascending and won't repeat, you could just use `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(i = cumsum(y > 0))

## Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
## Groups: group [2]
## 
##        x          y group     i
##    <int>      <dbl> <int> <int>
## 1      0    0.00000     1     0
## 2      0    0.00000     1     0
## 3      1   41.79209     1     1
## 4      1   57.73478     1     2
## 5      1  441.58968     1     3
## 6      1 1541.61783     1     4
## 7      0    0.00000     2     0
## 8      0    0.00000     2     0
## 9      0    0.00000     2     0
## 10     1  141.78670     2     1
## 11     1  432.98895     2     2
## 12     1  638.24612     2     3
```

or in base,

```
dat2$i <- ave(dat2$y, dat2$group, FUN = function(x){cumsum(x > 0)})
```

If you're not assured of those assumptions about `y`, e.g. if you wanted to add column `i` directly to `dat`, you could use `dplyr::dense_rank`, subtracting 1 to start at zero:

```
dat2 %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(i = dense_rank(y) - 1)
```

which you could reconstruct in base:

```
dat2$i <- ave(dat2$y, dat2$group, FUN = function(x){
    r <- rank(x); 
    match(r, sort(unique(r))) - 1
})
```

All return the same values.